# view zenith angle of MODIS surface reflectance product and Landsat 8

Tags: modis, landsat-8, reflectance

I have a MODIS daily surface reflectance product (MYD09GA) which I'd like to validate Landsat 8 image with. I want to obtain pixels that only fall within the view zenith angle of Landsat 8 ( 0 - 7.5). I have used the the scale factor of 0.01 to scale my MODIS imagery so it falls within the valid range of 0 - 18000. Having tried a lot of overlapping images with my Landsat, I've not found MODIS product that has very low view zenith angle like 7.5. The least I've seen is ~30. Wondering if anybody has used this/has experience what could be going on. Does it have to do with my area or I still need to rescale my MODIS to be comparable with Landsat?